# What is $\mathbb E[X\mid \sin(X)]$ when $X$ is uniform on $[0,\pi]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,\pi]$. Find $\mathbb{E}[X \mid\sin (X)]$.

My attempt:

$$\mathbb{E}[X\mid \sin (X)] = \int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{1}{\pi} f_{X\mid \sin (X)}(x) \,  \mathrm{d}x$$

How would I calculate $f(X\mid \sin (X))$?

Comment: Perhaps one can use symmetry to bypass computation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your hint. I am very confused though. I think I should use symmetry here. Basically, given that I know sin(X), I can infer the expected value of X by symmetry. I drew a picture and still don't understand!

Comment: Let $Y=\sin(X)$. Informally, given that $Y$ is between $y$ and $y+dy$, there are two possibilities for $X$. It could be between $\arcsin y$ and $\aecsin(y+dy)$, or between $\pi-\arcsin(y+dy)$ and $\pi-\arcsin y$, mean $\pi/2$. This is true for all $y$ between $0$ and $1$, so the conditional mean is $\pi/2$. This simple argument only works because of the special nature of $[0,\pi]$. If a formal answer is not given, I may write one.

Comment: You're mixing capital and lower-case letters in an incorrect way.  It is perfectly correct to say $\displaystyle \operatorname{E}(X\mid\sin X)$ or $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac 1 \pi f_{X\,\mid\,\sin X}(x)\,dx$.  Notice I'm using capital letters to refer to random variables and lower-case $x$ as the variable with respect to which one integrates.  There's a reason why it's done that way. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy - Will fix this

Comment: I'm no probabilist, but I don't see how this could have come out as anything but $E(X)$. "What do you expect $X$ to be, given that you know its sine?" Surely, whatever I expected $X$ to be in the first place!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might help to take a look at the graph of sin(x), $0\leq x \leq \pi$.
You see that once you know the value of sin($x$) (let's call this value $y_0$), there are only two possible values left for $x$.
Moreover, the function sin(x) is symmetric in x = $\pi/2$. So the two possible values for $x$ are distributed symmetrically around x = $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Let's call these values $x_0$ = arcsin($y_0$) and $x_1 = \pi - x_0$.

Since the initial distribution for $X$ was uniform, there is no preference for $x_0$ or $x_1$. The probability density function now becomes some sort of probability mass function (for discrete random variables).
P($X = x_0|\text{sin}(X) = y_0$) = 1/2
P($X = x_1|\text{sin}(X) = y_0$) = 1/2
And now we can easily calculate that $\mathbb{E}[X|\text{sin}(X) = y_0]$ = $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Note that this argument works for all values of $y_0$ between 0 and 1.
We can therefore conclude that
$\mathbb{E}[X|\text{sin}(X)]$ = $\frac{\pi}{2}$.